# Installing update with aborted download

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I never bothered installing windows uploads until recently.

While downloading the n-th batch of 139 important updates, my laptop started going really slow. Typing in a chat, switching chrome tabs, alt-tabbing to a game that also froze, everything took ages and some services died (like QuickSet, whatever it is). I decided to abort the installation but since even that didn't work I just terminated Windows Updater.

At that moment the update had been stuck at 130/139 for at least 2 hours.

Later, I restarted my laptop.
Now it's trying to install update 130/139, which I'm pretty sure I didn't even completely download. I know it might just be a long update and "only" 1h has passed, but I fear the update being literally impossible to complete.

**What should I do** to get mylaptop operative again, without spending money on it and with the minimum data loss possible?

I'm working on Windows 7 Ultimate SP 1 on a second hand DELL XPS whose Windows installation DVD I don't have.

Comment: Do you have a Windows install DVD?

Comment: @cybernard Nope. The laptop came to me without it. I thik I have a Vista DVD from a previous PC (if it still works) but that doesn't realy help, is it?

Comment: I would try just rebooting first, incase you didn't do that.

Comment: The Vista DVD should allow you to get to command prompt and backup your data as stated below.

Comment: What kind of Windows 7 is it home/premium/pro/ultimate?  What is the brand name of the laptop? HP?

Comment: Obviously do not install Vista.

Comment: Press F8 when the screen is still black. If rebooting doesn't work,  reboot again and start pressing the F8 key (1-2 times a second, stop if it starts beeping) and try to get to Safe Mode.  Does that work?

Comment: @cybernard I'm trying to get a working method before even trying to abort the install. Maybe it will just complete. BTW, I added some details on the possible cause of this mess.

Comment: If Safe mode works use system restore under accessories->system tools->system restore to restore to a backup point before the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an external hard drive.
Boot from a Windows install **DVD** **NOT** a recovery DVD or partition.
Boot from DVD
English (I assume)
**Repair computer**
**Command Prompt**
use the DOS copy command to copy only important files to your external hard drive.

Re-install windows (**do not format or delete the partition**)
If you get lucky there should be a **windows.old** folder that contains all your old files.  If not good thing you made the backup.

You will have to re-install your software and move **Documents** and etc from Windows.old to c:\users\\Documents and etc.

Comment: In the end, a normal restart worked and I was worrying for nothing. Still, this is a really valid solutions for those with similar problems, I think.